# Javascript icon toggle using else-if

Tags: javascript, toggle

I would like to make bookmark and it has to be coded with `Javascript` and `else-if`. Could you please help with this issue?

```
    var iBookmark = document.createElement('I');
    iBookmark.setAttribute('id', 'bookmark' + ecgData.id);
    iBookmark.setAttribute('class', 'bookmark outline icon');
    iBookmark.setAttribute('value', 'bk-false');
    iBookmark.style.color = 'white';
```

```
      if (checkedID.className = 'bookmark outline icon') {
        checkedID.setAttribute('class', 'bookmark icon');
        console.log(true);
      } else {
        checkedID.setAttribute('class', 'bookmark outline icon');
        console.log(false);
      }
```

```
      if (checkedID.getAttribute('value', 'bk-false')) {
        checkedID.setAttribute('class', 'bookmark icon');
        checkedID.setAttribute('value', 'bk-true');
        console.log('true')
      } 

      else if (checkedID.getAttribute('value', 'bk-true')) {
        checkedID.setAttribute('class', 'bookmark outline icon');
        checkedID.setAttribute('value', 'bk-false');
        console.log('false')
      }
```

When I click it, it changes to `true` and stays there, and it doesn't change back to false when I keep clicking it. It stays with true from default false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line  `if (checkedID.className = 'bookmark outline icon') {`
is missing its second `=` and isn't evaluating the expression, it is assigning the value to the class name.
Fix by changing it to `if (checkedID.className == 'bookmark outline icon') {`